# bind 2 instances to a single form - netzke

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, netzke

I have designed a form using netzke. In the same page same form is repeated.
While submitting this form both objects should saved to DB.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an listener in a common parent component to the `apply` event of form A and then call `onApply` on form B. Do this also the other way around, but don't forget to check if the form is not loading and only call `onApply` then:

```
var formA = this. getComponent('...').getView(),
  formB = this. getComponent('...').getView();

formA.on('apply', function(){
  formA.isLoading = true;
  if(!formB.isLoading){
    formB.onApply();
  }
  formA.isLoading = false;
}, this);

formB.on('apply', function(){
  formB.isLoading = true;
  if(!formA.isLoading){
    formA.onApply();
  }
  formB.isLoading = false;
}, this);
```